# Combining MID and LEFT Functions in Excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-2019

I currently have data in a cell/column of a course name/number ex.: 2019FA Microbiology (BIO-214-S104A). I am currently using a mid function to extract the data within the parenthesis to narrow it down to BIO-214-S104A in a separate column and using the Left function to extract just the BIO-214 in another column as that is all I need for the end result. Is there a way I can combine the functions so I am not having two separate columns and functions to get the result I need?

Functions used: =MID(txt,SEARCH("(",txt)+1,SEARCH(")",txt)-SEARCH("(",txt)-1) and =LEFT(txt,7)

Comment: =MID(txt,SEARCH("(",txt)+1,SEARCH(")",txt)-SEARCH("(",txt)-1) and =LEFT(txt,7)

Comment: `=LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1,SEARCH(")",A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)-1),7)`.

Comment: Thanks, BigBen! It worked! :-)

Comment: Your combining Mid and Left function can be shortened to : =MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,7)